# Node.js process.domain is undefined sometimes

Tags: node.js

In Node.js project build with LoopbackJS I need to store data during request.

So I used [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) feature:

```
// pre-processing middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // create per request domain instance
  var domain = require('domain').create();

  // save request and response to domain, to make it accessible everywhere
  domain.req = req;
  domain.res = res;
  domain.run(next);
});
```

Later in required module:

```
Model.beforeRemote('**', function(oContext, oModel, next) {
    // Save method name for later use
    process.domain.remoteContext = {          /* Here is an error thrown */
      methodName: oContext.method.name
    };
    ...
    process.domain.res.send() // example of usage
})
```

BUT when I make request from Safari or IE, process.domain is sometimes undefined! Requesting from Chrome or Firefox works as expected. Any suggestions?

Error response:

```
{"error":{"name":"TypeError","status":500,"message":"Cannot set property 'remoteContext' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: Cannot set property 'remoteContext' of undefined\n    at module.exports (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/server/hooks/admin-remote.js:12:34)\n    at Function.Model.setup.ModelCtor.beforeRemote.args (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/lib/model.js:184:9)\n    at execStack (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:363:13)\n    at RemoteObjects.execHooks (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:372:10)\n    at RemoteObjects.invokeMethodInContext (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:512:8)\n    at async.series.results (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:610:21)\n    at _asyncMap (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17)\n    at async.eachSeries.iterate (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:149:13)\n    at async.eachSeries (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:165:9)\n    at _asyncMap (/Users/igormatyushkin/projects/Yash/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:13)"}}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where domain is undefined? Are you accessing the domain from the same scope where you defined it? In your code example, you are not actually attaching the domain to the process - I assume you do that somewhere else in your code? Also, please post the stack trace leading to the undefined error, it may contain a clue or two.

Comment: @RobertRossmann, I updated the code and added thrown error. `Process.domain` is initialized by node, when `domain.run()` is called and I access `process.domain.remoteContext ` later in other required modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out, that explisity binding req and res to domain at creation moment, solves undefined domains down in execution stack.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // create per request domain instance
  domain.create().run(function() {
    // explicit binding
    process.domain.add(req)
    process.domain.add(res)
    // save request to domain, to make it accessible everywhere
    process.domain.req = req;
    process.domain.res = res;
    next()
  });
});
```

Don't know why this happens, so I leave question open for other possible advices.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that domains [are not meant to be used to handle errors in this manner](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors). Domains are instead meant to be used to allow modules of an entire application to crash safely (for example, maybe you want to run 3rd party code in a sandbox). A domain is not necessary here (though you are, of course, free to use one)

Furthermore, `process.domain` is only set if the given function is executing from within the domain stack. You do not provide information about the Model's call site, so I can only assume that your model is being called from outside of this stack, which is causing the error.

Given that you're hooking to `beforeRemote`, which executes **before** a remote action is executed, I'm going to assume that is being called from outside of the domain stack, and thus `process.domain` being undefined is expected behaviour.

Comment: Assume that process.domain is missing out of call stack, but it is happens only when I make request from Safari or IE. Requesting from Chrome or Firefox works as expected.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in your question that you had tried with Chrome or Firefox, which is why I made the assumption - only that you had tried it in Safari and IE.

Answer (score 0):

It's important for reader's of this question to know that [Node's Domain module](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) has been deprecated and should not be used.

If you came here looking for a solution to this problem then you will be better off looking for something other than the Domain module.

> This module is pending deprecation. Once a replacement API has been finalized, this module will be fully deprecated. Most end users should not have cause to use this module. Users who absolutely must have the functionality that domains provide may rely on it for the time being but should expect to have to migrate to a different solution in the future.

Although this does not technically answer the OP's question I believe that it's the correct "solution" for most readers of this question.

An alternative to using Domain is the [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) module.

Comment: domain was re-implemented in node core with async-hooks, so I think this answer is outdated